# a jack of all trades is [a] master of none

Tags: indefinite-article

I'm wondering why the indefinite article "a" is not in the standard version of the proverb:

> A jack of all trades is [a] master of none.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: By the way, I'm mostly hearing this as having no "a" at the beginning either: "Jack of all trades, master of none".

Answer (score 5):

We can understand **master** as a role-noun there, which can be used "bare" without a determiner.

> He took him on as *apprentice*.

Consider the various role-nouns in [this character summary](https://books.google.com/books?id=oTAAtT1QfrIC&pg=PA4&dq=%22master+of+disguise%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjixsbgkpPWAhUb0IMKHVZaDJ84PBDoAQiIATAR#v=onepage&q=%22master%20of%20disguise%22&f=false):

[image: Zippo Bambino]

*Murder Under the Big Top: A Murder a la Carte Mystery Play* By Tom Chiodo

Comment: Agreed.  To put it in slightly different terms, we often don't use articles or determiners with things like titles or roles: He is *king of Denmark*, not *the king*; Tom was *captain*, not *the captain*, etc.

Comment: I think it would be worth explicitly making the point within this answer that although it's *possible* to omit the indefinite article in such constructions, this isn't actually *required*. Stylistically / idiomatically, I'd definitely *prefer* to omit it in OP's example, but I'm inclined to reverse that position with your own example. And I don't like it at all in, say, *I **worked as waiter** at Harrods,* though I can't say exactly why (but obviously others feel much the same, since Google Books claims 3150 instances of *worked as **a** waiter at*, but only 99 instances without the article).

Comment: @fumblefingers I think it has to do with perceived number. Something like Master works either way because there could be one master (sailing master if a ship for example) or several (a chess master) for a waiter you would almost always expect there to be more than one, so a waiter sounds more correct. Just my interpretation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I do make that point explicitly.  See modal **can**.

Comment: Wouldn't the reason for which you justified "is master of none" be (wrongly)  used to justify "John is teacher"?

Comment: "Master of none" is hardly a title, is it?

Comment: @Apollyon: "master" can be a title.  **of none** is a prepositional phrase, not part of the noun per se.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *She works up at the manor as scullery maid.* *His job here at Harrods was waiter until he sneezed on a patron's lunch.*

Comment: If it were a title, it would include that prepositional phrase, just like "John is Professor of Economics," But in terms of meaning, "master of none" makes no sense as a title; it is an attribute.

Comment: @Apollyon: It is not an attribute. It could be considered a mock title.  But there's no requirement to treat the phrase as structurally equivalent to Professor of Economics.

Comment: It is an attribute; it means "someone who is not good at anything."

Comment: If the "title theory" could work, how would you rule out "John is teacher"?

Comment: @Apollyon: that's a paraphrase, not an analysis of the noun. Following your lead, we would have to say that "patriarch" was an attribute  and therefore not a role (see the link I added to the answer).

Comment: If something is title, it can be capitalized in a sentence after the copula, can't it? Can "master of none" normally be capitalized as "...is Master of None"?

Comment: The "master of disguise" example can be considered to share the indefinite article with "great clown of the circus."

Comment: @Apollyon: We can easily cast "teacher" as a role. "He worked here *as teacher* for ten years but then got a masters degree in School Administration and is now Assistant Principal at the middle school." https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20teacher%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: What really matters is the situation after the copula. The example in the OP has the noun "master" after the copula, so any comparable example should also have a copula before the noun.

Comment: @Apollyon: And I don't accept your argument that  the article **a** before "clown" in the Zippo Bambino character summary must be understood as implicit before "master".

Comment: Nor must "master" be understood as detached from the indefinite article. In fact, to regard "master" as sharing that indefinite article is the natural interpretation.

Comment: And it were a title, why wouldn't it be capitalized on a par with "Patriarch of the Flying Bambinos"?

Comment: To interpret every Y as a title as in "John Doe is an X and Y" raises the question of what kind of independent evidence there is to justify a view.

Comment: @Apollyon: You keep equating "title" with "role-noun". They are not identical.  "Bitter rival" is a role noun in the character summary above, but not a title. "Catholic nun" is a role-noun there but not a title. These are "stock characters" or well-recognized well-established positions, occupations, callings, etc  (e.g. "scullery maid" is a role in "she works as scullery maid" but it is not necessarily a personal title.) It could be a job title, but it wouldn't have to be capitalized.

Comment: I [cite](https://books.google.com/books?id=W1MrAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA795&dq=%22is+teacher%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7wrWRmJPWAhWl14MKHZ_ICswQ6AEIaDAM#v=onepage&q=%22is%20teacher%22&f=false): "Man is teacher to himself as pupil."  Both nouns are cast as roles.

Comment: Ok. Just replace the "title" in my posts with "role." And answer whether there is independent evidence for treating one noun as a role but not another. For example, why isn't "a great clown of the circus" a role?

Comment: At this point, I suspect you're citing examples from an older stage of Modern English. Maybe "jack of all trades, master of none" is from  a time when such an antiquated form of English was spoken. In current English, an indefinite article is required in "John is a teacher," isn't it? Being a teacher is a job role, isn't it?

Comment: @Apollyon: And I suspect you do not understand what is meant when I say that we can **cast** the noun as a role.  *Man is teacher to himself as pupil* is perfectly valid in PDE. It's not an archaism or antiquated. The roles of Jack and Master on a ship may be antiquated, but the underlying grammatical notion of role is alive and well.

Comment: Remember, what we want to explain is why an indefinite article is lacking in some nouns following the copula. To say such nouns are "roles" would require independent evidence for rolehood. What makes a noun stand for a role anyway?

Comment: If you reread my comments, the answer to your question is staring you in the face. "... stock characters or well-recognized well-established positions, occupations, callings..."

Comment: But a clown is a stock character, isn't it? Why is the indefinite article used there?

Comment: Such nouns are being cast as roles.  Re "a clown". There is no obligation to cast a noun as a role.

Comment: So you're saying a clown is not a role there. But why? What makes a noun a role anyway? Any independent evidence or criteria?

Comment: Would you deny "a clown" is a stock character? That's your own criterion for rolehood. Do you want to reject it?

Comment: Occupation: Troll.   Why not "a troll" there?  He is jester to the king.  She is personal assistant to Mr. Jones.

Comment: Then you're saying a noun denoting an occupation does not need to be a role. Then it follows that such nouns may have an indefinite article. Then it follows that in "master of none," it is okay to say "Someone is a master of none."

Comment: But still, I am wondering how many people would seriously consider "master of none" to be a (job) role. That's stretching it, isn't it?

Comment: You're saying occupation is the criterion for rolehood. But "a clown" denotes an occupation, yet it has an indefinite article preceding it. At the same time, however, you're also saying "there is no obligation to cast a noun as a role.' It seems that you watnt to deny "a clown" is a role. But it fits your criterion to a T, doesn't it? Maybe what you truly want to say is a noun denoting a role may or may not have an indefinite article before it.

Comment: Did I ever say that you could not say "a master of none". No, I did not.  The grammatical concept of "role" extends well beyond "job roles" or "occupation".  As I said, it extends to stock characters in well-established genres, to interpersonal dynamics. *Who's [the] disciplinarian in your family?*   Over decades and centuries some of these phrases involving role nouns can become "fixed expressions", meaning "that's how people talk".  Native speakers do not  cogitate over their words, they just speak. It doesn't matter how many or how few understand why they say what they say.

Comment: Please read my words more carefully if you're going to throw them back at me. I never said "Occupation was *the* criterion for rolehood".   You're failing to grasp an important fact about language: it reveals the speaker's thought. There is no obligation for that speaker to cast clown as role. It is his prerogative to do so.  And there's more than one way to specify a role:  *Who's **the** disciplinarian in your house?*

Comment: If occupation is not your (one) criterion, then what is it? Being a stock character? Interpersonal dynamics? "A clown" fits all of these, yet it has an indefinite article.  But you said "There is no obligation to cast a noun as a role," suggesting "a clown" is not a role there. Isn't that what you are suggesting?

Comment: You could well have said, "a role may or may not have an indefinite article to it after the copula." That'd be much simpler. Still, the question remains why "John is a teacher" requires an indefinite article. (I am not talking about your "Man is teacher to himself as a pupil; please remove the part "as a pupil" and see if it's acceptable English.)

Comment: *No one man is leader of this commune. We all share in decisions and reach consensus.* Or  *She was teacher and he her humble student.*   Those are two examples where the noun is being cast as role without determiner. Do they not satisfy your demand that the example use BE? There is no one criterion except that it be a role, broadly understood. I've given examples of ways a noun can be a role.

Comment: Clown redux (Your "A clown has all of these"): There is no obligation to cast a noun as role.  The noun can be presented as an instance-noun, i.e. one of such, using the indefinite article.

Comment: You wrote: "You could well have said, "a role may or may not have an indefinite article to it after the copula. That'd be much simpler."  You just don't get it. You're not understanding what I mean when I use the verb **cast**.

Comment: Who is goalie here?   Who is the goalie here? Who is a goalie here?  The first two would probably get a response from the starting goalie, if the second string and third string goalies were showing normal deference to the starter.  But the third question might get replies from several players.

Comment: Is "a clown" a role anyway? You seem to deny it as a role, but it satisfies all of your criteria presented. But if it is not a role, how do you know? Your chain of reasoning seems circular: "a clown" is not a role because it has an indefinite article. "A clown" has an indefinite article because it is not a role. The question is what your independence evidence is for rolehood.

Comment: What do you mean by "cast" anyway? I am not a native speaker, so you may have to rephrase your statements if your intended meaning does not get across.

Comment: Perhaps if you had devoted some effort to looking up the word **cast** in a dictionary  I'd be willing to continue this discussion.

Comment: By "cast," you probably meant "to describe, or to regard something as." So you were saying it is optional to describe a noun as a role, even if that noun fulfills all the criteria of rolehood. One question, then, presents itself: How do you know that "a clown," which satisfies all the criteria of rolehood, is not a "role" there? Saying rolehood is optional does not explain why you don't rergard "a clown" as a role.

Answer (score 1):

To add to this both Jack and Master are maritime references around the 1800. And able seaman was called Jack as a general term and a master was a specific sailing role within the ship

Comment: Welcome to ELL.stackexchange.com. This is a Question and Answer site, not a discussion forum. Though what you've written may be interesting to some here, it doesn't actually answer the Question asked (about articles) and hence should not be posted as an Answer.

Comment: I think Warwick's contribution is directly relevant. Welcome to ELL, WF.